# iOS animate continuous background?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6

I'm creating an application for iOS6 and 7. I need to make a continuos background, meant: i got 2 pictures i want to loop, and make the "infinity" view. I have tried a lot of code examples, but every time my iPhone just go black when opening the application.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code i tried so far:

```
UIImage *cloudImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cloud.png"];

CALayer *cloud = [CALayer layer];
cloud.contents = (id)cloudImage.CGImage;
cloud.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, cloudImage.size.width, cloudImage.size.height);
cloud.position = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                             cloudImage.size.height / 2);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:cloud];

CGPoint startPt = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width + cloud.bounds.size.width / 2,
                              cloud.position.y);
CGPoint endPt = CGPointMake(cloud.bounds.size.width / -2,
                            cloud.position.y);

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPt];
anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPt];
anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim.duration = 8.0;
[cloud addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];
```

But i need to have 2 photos in a infinity loop. and that background image are scrolling up instead of sideways

Comment: Can you share the code for things that you've tried so far?

Comment: I just added the code to my question

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of the pictures you are making loop with empty views. So your screen will completely filled with those views. That is why your screen going to black. So before starting the infinite loop of views check for the pictures which is there or not.

Comment: I've just added the code to my question, do you have any idéers?

Answer (score 0):

where did you add this code?
some times viewDidLoad is not a good place for adding view codes!
try adding a code in viewDidLayoutSubviews or with a little delay to insure that the images load properly.

try this instead [self.view.layer addSublayer:cloud];
[self.view addSubview:cloud];